# SUM selected columns using alias and group by

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to perform calculations on select columns using aliases and a grouping by. Query is below(problem on line before the from):

```
select r.res_id, 
    r.arrive_date,
    r.depart_date,
    r.res_type,
   if(DATEDIFF(r.depart_date, r.arrive_date) >29, 'LT', 'ST') as 'StayType',
   SUM(r.rent + r.fee_arr_early + r.fee_dep_late + r.fee_peace_waiver + r.fee_pool + r.city_tax + r.fee_cleaning + r.fee_pet + r.fee_tshirt + r.fee_misc + r.fee_non_tax + r.fee_processing + r.fee_travel_ins + r.fee_event + r.fee_cancel) as 'folioTotal',
   coalesce((select SUM(g.amount) from guest_payments as g where g.resId = r.res_id and charge_type = 'charge' and approved = 'Y'),0) as 'payments',
   coalesce((select SUM(g.amount) from guest_payments as g where g.resId = r.res_id and charge_type = 'credit' and approved = 'Y'),0) as 'credits',
    (SUM('folioTotal') - SUM('payments') + SUM('credits')) as 'folioBalance'
from reservations as r
    join guest_payments as g
        on r.res_id = g.resId
        group by r.res_id
```

I've tried putting this inside another sum with the same outcome.

Comment: did you try a sum of SUM()'s instead of SUM() of a sum of fields for folioTotal?

Comment: What is the problem? Show us your tables.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: I can setup a sqlfiddle later today or tonight, but the problem is that folioBalance column comes back with 0s.

Comment: its not performing the calculation and if I do a select 'folioTotal' instead of running that sum, I get an error that folioTotal isn't found

Answer (score 0):

I was being stupid, I was referencing the aliases inside single ticks which is why it wasn't calculating. Solution:

```
select r.res_id, 
    r.arrive_date,
    r.depart_date,
    r.res_type,
    g.entry_date,
   if(DATEDIFF(r.depart_date, r.arrive_date) >29, 'LT', 'ST') as 'StayType',
   (select SUM(r.rent + r.fee_arr_early + r.fee_dep_late + r.fee_peace_waiver + r.fee_pool + r.city_tax + r.fee_cleaning + r.fee_pet + r.fee_tshirt + r.fee_misc + r.fee_non_tax + r.fee_processing + r.fee_travel_ins + r.fee_event + r.fee_cancel) from reservations as r where r.res_id = g.resId) as 'folioTotal',
   coalesce((select SUM(g.amount) from guest_payments as g where g.resId = r.res_id and charge_type = 'charge' ),0) as 'payments',
   coalesce((select SUM(g.amount)* -1 from guest_payments as g where g.resId = r.res_id and charge_type = 'credit' and approved = 'Y'),0) as 'credits',
    (select folioTotal - payments + credits)
from reservations as r
    join guest_payments as g
        on r.res_id = g.resId
        group by r.res_id
```